# How to integral $\int\limits_{0}^{\pi \over 6} {x \over \sqrt{1-2\sin{x}}}dx$ ..?

Tags: calculus

$$\int\limits_{0}^{\pi \over 6} {x \over \sqrt{1-2\sin{x}}}dx$$

I attempted lots of permutations but I can't solve it..
moreover, I don't know its convergence or divergence... please help!

Comment: Please show your `lots of permutations `.

Comment: I tried $\u = tan \x \over 2, \x-\pi \over 6=\t$ etc..

Comment: Close to $\pi/6-\epsilon$, the asymptotic behavior of the function is $c/\sqrt\epsilon$ and the integral converges.

Comment: @박윤수 add your attempts in your question instead of the comments. Also, don't use "etc" or any vague language. Show us where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2):

*This is not a serious answer. Just done for the fun of it.*

As Ekesh answered, there is no solution even using special functions.

For the fun of it, I tried to see what would give the magnificent approximation
$$\sin(x) \simeq \frac{16 (\pi -x) x}{5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -x) x}\qquad (0\leq x\leq\pi)$$  proposed by Mahabhaskariya of Bhaskara I, a seventh-century Indian mathematician that is to say more than $1400$ years ago.

This leads to a quite complex integral
$$I=\int\limits_{0}^{\pi \over 6}\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-\frac{32 (\pi -x) x}{5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -x) x}}}$$ The antiderivative can be computed in terms of various (ugly) elliptic integrals and the integral is such that
$$\frac{216}{\pi^2}I=16(4+3 i)\, \Pi \left(\frac{1-3i}{5};\sin
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{i-1}{6}}\right)|\frac{18-24i}{25}\right)-3 \left((3-4 i)+20(1+ i) F\left(\sin
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{i-1}{6}}\right)|\frac{18-24i}{25}\right)+4(1+3 i) E\left(\sin
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{i-1}{6}}\right)|\frac{18-24i}{25}\right)\right)$$
This is not nice at all but it evaluates to $I\approx 0.380381$ (relative error $=0.36$%).

Answer (score 1):

There is no elementary solution to the integral. However, using a numerical approximation technique, we have

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/6} \frac{x}{\sqrt{1 - 2\sin(x)}} \approx 0.379007.$$

Comment: Wolfram? is that you?

Comment: @Ekesh even if this is intended to be a hint, you should mention the type of numerical method or the steps required for the OP to get the answer. Please don't just copy and paste the answer from WA or a calculator.